# Choosing between uploading a file or entering a custom URL - HTML Forms

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a web form in which users have the option to set a custom profile picture. What I'm trying to do is to create a drop-down box that gives you the option to choose between uploading an image or linking an image from a URL.

The option that is not selected should be disabled, but I can't seem to get this to work.

---

Here is my code:

#### HTML:

```
<form>
Choose a Profile Picture:<br>
<select>
    
    <option onselect="upload()">Upload an Image
    <option onselect="link()">Load from URL
        
</select><br>
        
<input type="file" id="fileBrowse" accept="image/*"><br>
<input type="url" id="enterUrl" placeholder="Enter in a URL." disabled>
```

#### JS:

```
function upload() {
    document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = false;
    
}

function link() {
    document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = false;
}
```

---

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SplashHero/fbh9pevw/) for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `onselect` is not a valid event handler for an `option` element. You'll have to use `onchange`

**HTML**

```
<form>
    Choose a Profile Picture:<br>
    <select id="profilePictureType" onchange="onSelectChange()">

        <option value="1">Upload an Image</option>
        <option value="2">Load from URL</option>

    </select><br>

    <input type="file" id="fileBrowse" accept="image/*"><br>
    <input type="url" id="enterUrl" placeholder="Enter in a URL." disabled="disabled">

</form>
```

**JS**

```
function onSelectChange() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("profilePictureType").value;    
    selectedValue == "1" ? upload() : link();
}

function upload() {
    document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = false;

}

function link() {    
    document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktvjkthd/)

---

A short version of this solution would be

```
function onSelectChange() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("profilePictureType").value;    
    var upload = selectedValue == "1";

    document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = upload;
    document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = !upload;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the onchange into the select (not the options) and disable it based on the selected value

```
<form>
    Choose a Profile Picture:<br>
    <select id="choose" onchange="changed();">

        <option value="upload">Upload an Image</option>
        <option value="link">Load from URL</option>

    </select><br>

    <input type="file" id="fileBrowse" accept="image/*"><br>
    <input type="url" id="enterUrl" placeholder="Enter in a URL." disabled="disabled">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changed() {
    var chooser = document.getElementById("choose");
    var chooseValue = chooser.options[chooser.selectedIndex].value;
    if(chooseValue == "upload") {
        document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = false;
    } else if(chooseValue == "link") {
        document.getElementById("fileBrowse").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("enterUrl").disabled = false;
    }

}
</script>
```